# Generate XML tree structure from nested ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, xml, arraylist, hierarchy

My aim is to generate a tree structure in an XML file from a nested ArrayList containing File objects. I constructed the ArrayList by scanning a directory structure on my harddisk.

I want the XML file to look similar to the following:

```
<root>
     <layer1 name="">
        <layer2 name="">
           <layer3 name=""></layer3>
        </layer2>
     <layer1>
</root>
```

the XML should simply represent the hierarchical order of my folders and the `name`-attributes should be filled with the folder names.

Is there a simple way to realize this in Java?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it; if you decide which API you want to use (DOM, JDOM, code it all by hand, etc.) it would narrow down your choices.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution using [a library that supports creation of XML via XPath like expression](http://xmlbeam.org). (I am affiliated with that project)

```
public class CreateXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<String> fileEntries = Arrays.asList("/path1/path2/file.txt","/path1/path3/path4/file2.txt","/path5/file3.txt");
       DOMAccess domAccess = new XBProjector().projectEmptyDocument(DOMAccess.class);
       for (String entry:fileEntries) {
       String xpath="root";
            int i=0;
           for (String s:(entry.replaceFirst("\\/", "")).split("\\/")) {
               xpath+="/layer"+(++i)+"[@name='"+s+"']";
           }
           System.out.println(xpath);
           domAccess.create(xpath, "");
       }
       System.out.println(domAccess.asString());
    }
}
```

First thepaths are transformed to a xpath, then elments are created by these paths. The program prints out:

```
root/layer1[@name='path1']/layer2[@name='path2']/layer3[@name='file.txt']
root/layer1[@name='path1']/layer2[@name='path3']/layer3[@name='path4']/layer4[@name='file2.txt']

root/layer1[@name='path5']/layer2[@name='file3.txt']
<root>
  <layer1 name="path1">
    <layer2 name="path2">
      <layer3 name="file.txt"/>
    </layer2>
    <layer2 name="path3">
      <layer3 name="path4">
        <layer4 name="file2.txt"/>
      </layer3>
    </layer2>
  </layer1>
  <layer1 name="path5">
    <layer2 name="file3.txt"/>
  </layer1>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need only the top-most file in your hierarchy for this. If you don't know which is you can first sort your list, this will put the top-most file at the first position.

```
String parseFile(File file, int layer) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    if(file.isDirectory()) {
        if(layer == 0) {
            result.append("<root>");
            for(File childFile : file.listFiles()) {
                result.append(parseFile(childFile, layer + 1));
            }
            result.append("</root>");
        }
        result.append("<layer"+layer+" name=\""+file.getName()+"\">");
        for(File childFile : file.listFiles()) {
           result.append(parseFile(childFile, layer + 1));
        }
        result.append("</layer"+layer+">");
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

This will go on until the leaf directories, if you intend to parse strictly the files on your list you'll need to test:

```
String parseFile(List<File> originalFileList, File file, int layer) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    if(file.isDirectory()) {
        if(layer == 0) {
            result.append("<root>");
            for(File childFile : file.listFiles()) {
                if(originalFileList.contains(childFile)) {
                   result.append(parseFile(originalFileList, childFile, layer + 1));
                }
            }
            result.append("</root>");
        } else {
            result.append("<layer"+layer+" name=\""+file.getName()+"\">");
            for(File childFile : file.listFiles()) {
                if(originalFileList.contains(childFile)) {
                   result.append(parseFile(originalFileList, childFile, layer + 1));
                }
            }
            result.append("</layer"+layer+">");
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: XML should never be created manually by string concatenation. What if a path contains a char that needs to be escaped in XML? What about the file encoding?